# Could not make json data on spring 3.2 and got an error (Page not found 404)

Tags: javascript, json, spring-mvc, jackson, mybatis

I am trying to select data from a database using Sprng 3.2, myBatis and want to receive data formatted as JSON.

I put jackson-core-asl, jackson-core-lgpl and jackson-mapper-asl(1.9.13) in the pom.xml

When I send a request to the server, then I got an error "HTTP Status 404 - /WEB-INF/jsp/listJson.jsp" . I wonder why my configuration file doesn't work for @ResponseBody.

I googled it a lot but still have an error. it doesn't work on spring 3.2?

When I put this below instead of `<mvc:annotation-driven />`
it works well. But as I know AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter is deprecated on spring 3.2.

```
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
<beans:property name="messageConverters">
    <beans:list>
        <beans:bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter" />
    </beans:list>
</beans:property>
```

1. servlet-context.xml

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

2 Controller

```
@Controller
public class BoardController
{
    @Autowired
    private MainService mainService;

    @RequestMapping("/listJson.do")
    public @ResponseBody
        Map<?, ?> listJson(@RequestParam Map<String, Object> paramMap, ModelMap model) throws Throwable
    {
        model.put("results", mainService.getList(paramMap));
        return model;
    }
}
```

Comment: HTTP 404 informs about wrong URL/link. Are you sure, that you are invoking valid URL?

Comment: Hi Michal, Yes I am very sure about that. <mvc:annotation-driven> doesn't work. It just passes and try to call the page(listJson.jsp). so I think I get an error.

Answer (score 0):

The following configuration works for me!

Just put `<mvc:annotation-driven>` is not enough to render json format data.
and in tomcat log console,I found the HandlerMapping in use was RequestMappingHandlerMapping

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />

<beans:bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="mediaTypes">
        <beans:map>
            <beans:entry key="html" value="text/html" />
            <beans:entry key="json" value="application/json" />
        </beans:map>
    </beans:property>
    <beans:property name="viewResolvers">
        <beans:bean
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
            <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
            <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
        </beans:bean>
    </beans:property>
    <beans:property name="defaultViews">
        <beans:list>
            <beans:bean
                class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJackson2JsonView" />
        </beans:list>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>
```